# Chart in MVC application for date wise punch In-Out time

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, chart.js, linechart

I am using visual studio 2019 and developing a MVC application. I want to render a chart between in-time (on Y-Axis) and attendance date (on X-Axis) for employee attendance date wise. I am getting all those data of the employee as an object list. Please refer screenshots. [Attendance Date Object List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1imy.png)

[Punch In-Time Object List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VvYe.png)

I am using Chart.js (V 3.7.1) in MVC application. I have googled a lot but can't find the solution. I am new to this platform, please help me out to find out the solution to do that? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code of Action Method:

[HttpGet]

```
    public ActionResult BarChart()
    {
        try
        {
            List<object> iData = new List<object>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(AppSetting.OraConnectionString()))
            {
                string str = @"SELECT to_char(cast(EAE_DATE as date),'dd-MON-yy') AS EAE_DATE ,to_char(cast(IN_TIME as date),'hh24:mi:ss') AS IN_TIME,to_char(cast(OUT_TIME as date),'hh24:mi:ss') AS OUT_TIME FROM EMPLOYEE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE_EXL WHERE EAE_EM_ID = 904 AND EAE_YEAR=2022 AND EAE_MONTH=11 ORDER BY EAE_DATE";

                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(str, con);
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    List<object> x = new List<object>();
                    x = (from DataRow drr in dt.Rows select drr[dc.ColumnName]).ToList();
                    iData.Add(x);
                }
                ViewBag.Date_List = iData[0];
                ViewBag.InTime_List = iData[1];
                ViewBag.OutTime_List = iData[2];

            }

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And View code is:

```js
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BarChart";
}
<div style="text-align: center">
    <canvas id="barcanvas"></canvas>
</div>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Attendance Punctuality</title>
@* I have installed Chart.js from ManageNugetPackages so not using the cdn *@
   
<script>
    var DayDate =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Date_List));
    var InTime =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.InTime_List));
    var OutTime =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.OutTime_List));
    var ChartData =
        { labels: DayDate,
          datasets: [{
                            label: 'In Time',
                            backgroundColor: "#aad2ed",
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            data: InTime,
                            borderColor: '#0062ff',
                            fill: false,
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Out Time',
                            backgroundColor: "#f7bd83",
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            data: OutTime,
                            borderColor: '#F78511',
                            fill: false,
                      }]
        };
            window.onload = function () {
                var ctx1 = document.getElementById("barcanvas").getContext("2d");
                window.myBar = new Chart(ctx1,
                    { type: 'line',       //line,pie,bar,doughnut
                        data: ChartData,
                        showDatapoints: true,
                        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                        options:
                            {
                                title: { display: true, text: "Attendance Trial Graph"},
                                responsive: true,
                                maintainAspectRatio: true
                            }
                    });
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us your code to generate the chart.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mr. Panchal. I have post the code. May be the problem is related to conversion but I couldn't do that.

Comment: Anybody knows the answer ?